# How to adjust my table size to show up completely?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
 \hline\hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pre-block}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Post-block} & Paired \textit{t}-test   \\ 
\cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-6}

        &  Mean   & Standard error                                                  &   Mean          
    & Standard error    & \textit{t}-stats                                                  \\    \hline
Panel A. Contributions from all contributors&            &            &            &            &            \\
Addition    &     1105.53&      225.67&      538.01&      117.00&        2.89\\
Deletion    &      528.96&      167.25&      174.57&       38.21&        2.32\\
Total       &     1634.49&      389.77&      712.58&      153.13&        2.69\\
\hline
\addlinespace[0.3cm]
Panel B. Contributions from nonblocked contributors&            &            &            &            &            \\
Addition    &     3592.67&      787.90&     1887.40&      408.73&        2.48\\
Deletion    &     1798.83&      585.61&      612.42&      133.49&        2.22\\
Total       &     5391.50&     1362.84&     2499.82&      534.91&        2.41\\

\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion using `\multicolumn` for the "Panel A..." and "Panel B..." texts, `booktabs`(that you already loaded) for the horizontal lines (especially for the `\cmidrule` commands to add a small horizontal white space between adjacent `\cmidrule`s) and `siunitx` for an improved alignment of the numbers. To make the whole table even narrower, I have abbreviated the term "standard error". Alterntively you could also split the words into two lines to save some horizontal space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{S[table-format=4.2]} S[table-format=3.2] S[table-format=1.2]}
 \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pre-block}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Post-block} & {Paired \textit{t}-test}   \\ 
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6}

            &  {Mean}    & {Std Err } &   {Mean}   & {Std Err}  & {\textit{t}-stats} \\    \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Panel A. Contributions from all contributors} \\
Addition    &     1105.53&      225.67&      538.01&      117.00&        2.89\\
Deletion    &      528.96&      167.25&      174.57&       38.21&        2.32\\
Total       &     1634.49&      389.77&      712.58&      153.13&        2.69\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Panel B. Contributions from nonblocked contributors} \\
Addition    &     3592.67&      787.90&     1887.40&      408.73&        2.48\\
Deletion    &     1798.83&      585.61&      612.42&      133.49&        2.22\\
Total       &     5391.50&     1362.84&     2499.82&      534.91&        2.41\\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{S[table-format=4.2]} S[table-format=3.2] S[table-format=1.2]}
 \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pre-block}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Post-block} & {Paired \textit{t}-test}   \\ 
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6}

            &  {Mean}    & {\makecell{Standard\\ error}} &   {Mean}   & {\makecell{Standard\\ error}}  & {\textit{t}-stats} \\    \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Panel A. Contributions from all contributors} \\
Addition    &     1105.53&      225.67&      538.01&      117.00&        2.89\\
Deletion    &      528.96&      167.25&      174.57&       38.21&        2.32\\
Total       &     1634.49&      389.77&      712.58&      153.13&        2.69\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Panel B. Contributions from nonblocked contributors} \\
Addition    &     3592.67&      787.90&     1887.40&      408.73&        2.48\\
Deletion    &     1798.83&      585.61&      612.42&      133.49&        2.22\\
Total       &     5391.50&     1362.84&     2499.82&      534.91&        2.41\\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Letting the "Panel A. ..." and "Panel B. ..." protrude into the other columns, via `\multicolumn{6}{l}{...}` wrapppers, will get you most of the way -- compare the looks of Tables 1 and 2 below. However, this change alone won't guarantee that the table will actually fit completely inside the text block.

Here are some additional suggestions, in no particular order:

- Use a `tabular*` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, and let LaTeX figure out the permissible amount of intercolumn whitespace.
- Use the commands of the `booktabs` package more consistently. So far, you use `\addlinespace`, but you do not use `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\cmidrule`. Using these commands instead of `\hline` and `\cline`, respectively, will greatly reduce impressions of crampedness and claustrophobia.
- Align the numbers in five data columns on their respective decimal columns. This may be done with the help of the `S` column type, which is provided by the `siunitx` package.
- Abbreviate the headers `Standard error` to `Std. error`, to balance the appearance of the first four data columns.

These ideas are implemented in Table 3 below.

(The vertical lines in the following screenshot denote the edges of the text block.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}   % for 'S' column type
\usepacakge{showframe} % denote edges of textblock
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{OP's original form}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\hline\hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pre-block}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Post-block} & Paired \textit{t}-test   \\ 
\cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-6}
        &  Mean   & Standard error                                                  &   Mean          
    & Standard error    & \textit{t}-stats                                                  \\    \hline
Panel A. Contributions from all contributors&            &            &            &            &            \\
Addition    &     1105.53&      225.67&      538.01&      117.00&        2.89\\
Deletion    &      528.96&      167.25&      174.57&       38.21&        2.32\\
Total       &     1634.49&      389.77&      712.58&      153.13&        2.69\\
\hline
\addlinespace[0.3cm]
Panel B. Contributions from nonblocked contributors&            &            &            &            &            \\
Addition    &     3592.67&      787.90&     1887.40&      408.73&        2.48\\
Deletion    &     1798.83&      585.61&      612.42&      133.49&        2.22\\
Total       &     5391.50&     1362.84&     2499.82&      534.91&        2.41\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}
\caption{Let header lines protrude out of column 1}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\hline\hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pre-block}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Post-block} & Paired \textit{t}-test   \\ 
\cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-6}
        &  Mean   & Standard error                                                  &   Mean          
    & Standard error    & \textit{t}-stats                                                  \\    \hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Panel A. Contributions from all contributors} \\
Addition    &     1105.53&      225.67&      538.01&      117.00&        2.89\\
Deletion    &      528.96&      167.25&      174.57&       38.21&        2.32\\
Total       &     1634.49&      389.77&      712.58&      153.13&        2.69\\
\hline
\addlinespace[0.3cm]
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Panel B. Contributions from nonblocked contributors} \\
Addition    &     3592.67&      787.90&     1887.40&      408.73&        2.48\\
Deletion    &     1798.83&      585.61&      612.42&      133.49&        2.22\\
Total       &     5391.50&     1362.84&     2499.82&      534.91&        2.41\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}
\caption{Further improvements}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l *{3}{S[table-format=4.2]} 
         S[table-format=3.2]
         S[table-format=1.2] }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pre-block}  
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Post-block} 
& {Paired $t$-test}   \\ 
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-6}
& {Mean} & {Std.\ error} & {Mean} & {Std.\ error} & {$t$-stats} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Panel A\@. Contributions from all contributors}  \\
Addition    &     1105.53&      225.67&      538.01&      117.00&        2.89\\
Deletion    &      528.96&      167.25&      174.57&       38.21&        2.32\\
Total       &     1634.49&      389.77&      712.58&      153.13&        2.69\\
\addlinespace[0.3cm]
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Panel B\@. Contributions from nonblocked contributors} \\
Addition    &     3592.67&      787.90&     1887.40&      408.73&        2.48\\
Deletion    &     1798.83&      585.61&      612.42&      133.49&        2.22\\
Total       &     5391.50&     1362.84&     2499.82&      534.91&        2.41\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```